# rails 4: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code on a rails 4 application

```
query= OrderHeader.select("orders_header.id, 
  orders_header.created_at").where("shop_id=#{shop_id} and 
  customer_id=#{customer_id} and hash_key like 
    '#{current_hash_key}'").order("id desc") 
       if query.nil? 
         return true # no duplicates found 
      end 
      if (query.count>0) # duplicates found 
         #nothing
      end
```

and I get the error

ERROR

> SELECT COUNT(orders_header.id, orders_header.created_at) FROM 
>   `orders_header`  WHERE (shop_id=99 and customer_id=1 and hash_key like
>   '539de64e8793790430052bc861dd0ff521334e32')
>
> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
>   use near ' orders_header.created_at) FROM `orders_header`  WHERE 
>   (shop_id=99 and customer_' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(orders_header.id, 
>   orders_header.created_at) FROM `orders_header`  WHERE (shop_id=99 and 
>   customer_id=1 and hash_key like 
>   '539de64e8793790430052bc861dd0ff521334e32')

Comment: I have this error when I navigate to rails admin and try to edit one of my users.do you have any  ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you recently upgraded to rails 4.1? In that case it could the known issue mentioned here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15138

Answer (score 0):

You need to use plural form for table names inside the string, `orders_headers.id` not `orders_header.id`, and so on, also to avoid sql injection, you should use params passed to the string not put your params inside the string, eg:

```
where("shop_id=?", shop_id)
```

so to clean your whole where statement it could be something like this

```
where(shop_id: shop_id, customer_id: customer_id).where("hash_key like '?'",current_hash_key)
```